# What's the QMetaCallEvent for and how to access its details?

Tags: qt, events, filter, meta, qevent

I have an event filter and I noticed when I click to expand/collapse a tree branch I get `QEvent::MetaCall`. I was thinking about using this to roll my own expand/collapse code, but I don't know how to get any information, such as the index of the item.

**Is there anything available from this MetaCall event type?**

I found someone had asked this same question on another site, but without an answer, here:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37525-How-to-filter-QEvent-MetaCall

What is this event typically used for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The biggest question are: *What exactly are you trying to do? What is the Qt class that received those events?* As far as I'm concerned, you're trying to do things the hard way, so why bother?

The `QMetaCallEvent` is the event representing a slot call whenever a **queued connection** is used to invoke a slot. This might be due to a signal firing that was connected to a slot, or due to the use `QMetaObject::invoke` or `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`. The queued connection bit is the important part! Queued connections are **not** used by default for calls between objects in the same thread, since they have the event queue management overhead, unless either of the two conditions below holds true:

1. You provide `Qt::QueuedConnection` argument to `QObject::connect` or `QMetaObject::invoke[Method]`, *or*
2. The receiving object's `thread()` is different from the thread where the call is originating - at the time of the call.

The [`QMetaCallEvent`](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject_p.h.html#361) event class carries the information needed to invoke a slot. It contains the sender `QObject` and its signal id (if the call comes from a signal-slot connection), as well as the target slot identifier, and the arguments needed to be passed into the slot.

Thus, you could check if the called slot is the one you wish to intercept, as well as what arguments were passed to it. For example, if you're calling a slot with a single `int` parameter, then `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(metaCallEvent->args()[1])` will give you the value of that integer. The zero-th argument is used for the return value, if any, so the parameters are indexed with base 1.

**Disclaimer** Since the `QMetaCallEvent` class is internal to Qt's implementation, you're making your application's binary tied to the particular Qt version in full (entire major.minor version) and you lose the benefits of binary compatibility offered by Qt across the major version. Your code may still compile but cease to work properly when you switch to another minor version of Qt!

The below applies to Qt 5.2.0, I have not looked at any other versions!

So, suppose you want to intercept a call to `QLabel::setNum`. You'd catch such events as follows:

```
#include <private/qobject_p.h> // Declaration of QMetaCallEvent

bool Object::eventFilter(QObject * watched, QEvent * event) {
  QLabel * label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(watched);
  if (! label || event->type() != QEvent::MetaCall) return false;
  QMetaCallEvent * mev = static_cast<QMetaCallEvent*>(event);
  static int setNumIdx = QLabel::staticMetaObject.indexOfSlot("setNum(int)");
  if (mev->id() != setNumIdx) return false;
  int num = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(mev->args()[1]);
  // At this point, we can invoke setNum ourselves and discard the event
  label->setNum(num);
  return true;
}
```

If you want to see, globally, all slots that are called using the metacall system, you can do that too. Template parametrization of the base class allows flexibility to use any application class - say `QCoreApplication`, `QGuiApplication`, `QApplication`, or a user-derived type.

```
template <class Base> class MetaCallWatcher : public Base {
  MetaCallWatcher(int& argc, char** argv) : Base(argc, argv) {}
  bool notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) { 
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MetaCall) {
      QMetaCallEvent * mev = static_cast<QMetaCallEvent*>(event);
      QMetaMethod slot = receiver->metaObject()->method(mev->id());
      qDebug() << "Metacall:" << receiver << slot.methodSignature();
    }
    return Base::notify(receiver, event);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  MetaCallWatcher<QApplication> app(argc, argv);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I can not include `private/qobject_p.h`, compiler doensn't see it.

Comment: @Efog You must have a full installation of Qt done from sources. In your case, the sources aren't present, so the private headers aren't present either.

Comment: This works as long as you use the old string based signal/slot connections. With function pointers, QMetaCallEvent.id() does not contain a helpful information anymore. This is the best I could squeeze out of the new signal/slot connections: https://gist.github.com/webmaster128/2d4df2e46818d4e76fb7f7b8940c841a

Comment: For some reason, I have to include this path: `#include <QtCore/5.6.0/QtCore/private/qobject_p.h>` to get the "private" headers. I have a suspition this is intentional to force me to include particular Qt version due to aforementioned compatibility issues.

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. Add `QT += core_private` to the `.pro` file, and `#include <private/qobject_p.h>`, then delete the build folder of your project and rebuild. It will work. There's never a question of what version you're using: the current one you build the project with. Feel free to look for this include in any of my stackoverflow answers on github, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `QEvent::MetaCall`-type event is created whenever a signal has been emitted that is connected to a slot in the receiving `QObject`. Reacting to this event in a custom filter/event handler seems to circumvent Qt's mightiest feature, the signal-slot architecture. It's probably better to find out which slot is called and if that slot is virtual so you can overload it.

Comment: Thank you for the information. To accept an answer, I would still like to know what it is used for, perhaps in a real-world example, and if there is anything available from the QEvent type.

Comment: It is false that the `QMetaCallEvent` is created whenever a connected signal is emitted. It would make the signal-slot mechanism much slower than necessary.

Answer (score -2):

`QEvent::MetaCall` is used for delivering cross-thread signals.