# Can I get Qt to profile signal-slot execution duration?

Tags: c++, qt, profiling, signals-slots

I have a Qt console application on windows. I want to profile it, but QtCreator profiling does not work on windows.

I have just a few signals/slots which I use. The aplication is single threaded, every connection is `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Could Qt log how much time it took to execute every slot that was called from the event loop? It would help me finding CPU bottleneck without manually adding timers everywhere in the program.

Is it maybe possible to override the slot calling mechanism and measure time when the called slot was executing?

Comment: Note that even if there is some hack or alternative profiling solution, I am still looking for answer on how to profile slot execution in particular.

Comment: Slot is a general function. Why can't you use a profiler to measure how much time it takes to execute a function?

Comment: @vahancho Because I don't know any general purpose profiler that works reliably on windows. Trust me, I tried lot of them and they all sucked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queued slot calls are delivered as a `QMetaCallEvent` to the receiving `QObject`. Thus you could time the `QCoreApplication::notify` when it delivers these events: the `QObject::event` is invoked from within that method.

There are two aspects of this:

1. Timing and data collection - see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25118309/1329652) for a complete example.
2. Decoding the contents of `QMetaCallEvent` to know which method was called - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10887157/1329652).

Comment: So I implemented this and it kinda works. But the problem is that I use the compile time signal/slot syntax (&MyClass::mySlot) and target->metaObject()->method(metaCall->id()).methodSignature‌​() always returns empty string because the meta method is invalid. Can you add more detail, or should I ask another question specifically about this?

Comment: The linked question is still valid, it just needs another answer that deals with modern call syntax. It's an easy fix to get the method signature from the new syntax as well. I just didn't get to it yet.

Comment: Is there anything I could have a look on to figure it out? It's not like I need it that desperatelly - at this point I'm better off using manual timers in methods - but I find this digging in Qt internal stuff quite interesting.